# How best to implement a Dashboard from data in HDFS/Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I have a bunch of data in .csv format in Hadoop HDFS in several GBs.i have Flight data on one airport. there are different delays like carrier delay, weather delay. NAS delay etc

I want to create a dashboard that reports on the contents in there e.g maximum delay on particular route, maximum delay flight wise etc.

I am new to hadoop world.

thnak you

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hive. Similar like SQL.

You can load the data from HDFS into tables using simple create table statements.

Hive also provides in-built functions which you can exploit to get the necessary results.

Many Data Visualizations tools are available, some commonly used are

- Tableau
- Qlik
- Splunk

These tools provide us capabilities to create our own dashboard.

Comment: i want to create dashboard  so how can i visualize the data on any webpage ? do i need to store result in RDBMS and then i can show it to the dashboard ?

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to store in HDFS ( not in RDBMS ).